# How can I give multiple users/groups acl permissions for the same folder?

Tags: powershell, directory, permissions, acl

So I have a Folder structure Script that creates folders with their permissions from an Excel list.
in that list there are columns for specific permissions, in theses colums I wanna write the usernames that I wanna give the permissions to. the Scripts is programmed that it goes line by line in the Excel file. so that being said, I want the usernames to be written on one line. now when I write one name it works but with multiple names it doesn't, I have converted the whole cell to and array, Tried using the foreach loop. still doesn't work. 
here is that part of the Script:

```
$acl = Get-Acl $homedir
$FileSystemRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
$AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"None"
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($users, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
```

so `$users` here is the excel cell where the usernames are and they look like this

```
user1,user2
```

now the foreach loop is a good solution but somehow it's not working and always giving `"Cannot convert value "user1" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format"`
can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Consider using this module: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity/4.2.4
It is really easy to use, quite flexible, and you do not need to complicate your life, using types. I have used it on a multiple occasions and it works like a charm! Not only to apply permissions, but also to audit and report.

Comment: Also a tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fieldcoding/ntfssecurity-tutorial-1-getting-adding-and-removing-permissions

Comment: Edit your code to reflect what you've tried. A `ForEach-Object` loop should work fine

Comment: Thanks! but I kinda need to get this done with a script, because this is an on-going process in my company and the whole purpose of the script is to automate the whole thing so we don't have to do it manually anymore.

Comment: Please show some of your Excel file. If all users are in one cell, separated by commas, the get the cell's value, split on the comma to get an array of users and loop through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, What **Scepticalist** suggested seems to solve the problem.
had to use foreach-object loop instead of the foreach loop.
the working code:

```
$users | ForEach-Object{
$acl = Get-Acl $homedir
$FileSystemRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Fullcontrol"
$AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"None"
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($_, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
$acl.setAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "$homedir"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
$acl = Get-Acl $homedir
$FileSystemRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
$AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"None"

foreach ($user in $users) {

    $ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("$user",$FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
    $acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
}
```